# Get value from rows not null XLSXWRITER (python)

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I want to merge column 2 (with "description") same to column 1(with "name") : same number of rows to merge , but when using merge_range I got null value in the column 2.

Here is my code.

```
 my_list = [
            {'field1': [
                {'name': 'value1', 'description': ""
                 },
                {'name': 'value1', 'description': "this is descr..."
                 },
                {'name': 'value1', 'description': ""
                 },

            ]
             },
        ]
        row = 206
        for record in my_list:
            row_mem = row
            for rec in record['field1']:
                sheet.write(row, 2, rec['description'])
                row += 1
            sheet.merge_range(row_mem, 1, row - 1, 1, rec['name'])
```

Result:
[image]

when replacing `sheet.write(row, 2, rec['description'])`by

```
sheet.merge_range(row_mem, 2, row - 1, 2, rec['description'])
```

I got this result :
[image]

But I want to display it like this:
[image]

How I can merge column 2 and get the not null value when merging it .

Any help please ? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. How does one merge a column with a value? Can you provide an example with some actual data, as well as the expected result? What did you try yourself? Please share your code and explain exactly where you're stuck. Also check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: post updated with example @Grismar,  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The indent on your code sample is invalid, I'll assume that the lines `row = 206` and `for record in my_list:` should be at the same indent as `my_list=` and the lines below `for record ...`  retain the same indent in relation to that line.
With your code as it is; for the `'description'` column the value to retain is in the 2nd cell, so the 3 cells being merged are **empty string, string value, empty string**. In usual case when cells are merged the top left cell coordinate and value are retained any values in other cells are lost. *Therefore if these 3 cells are merged the result is a cell with empty string*.

However your code does not merge the cells as is, from the description text this is achieved by replacing

```
sheet.write(row, 2, rec['description'])
```

with

```
sheet.merge_range(row_mem, 2, row - 1, 2, rec['description'])
```

Since that means you are merging the description column on each loop I'd expect that'd give you a `warning` from attempting to merge a single cell on the first loop, then merge two cells, **empty string** & **string value** on the second loop. So as mentioned above the cells would merge retaining the top left value, this being the **empty string**.

Not sure what your ultimate aim is but I think it's better you do as you have for the `'name'` cells and just merge together the cells you want with the value.
The loop may not be required but assuming you have a few fields in the list `mylist` then something like this may be your better option.

For clarity I have added a second field to `my_list` called `field2` and the original is called `field1`. I have used a range count to track the rows. The range starts at 206 and steps by 3 for the three rows to be merged. The max value for the range is an arbitrary number. It doesn't need to be specific only large enough to encompass the rows used, the `my_list` loop will govern when the loop ends.

```
range(206, 1000, 3)
```

On 1st loop cycle the `row is set to 206` and the `name` and `description` are written to merged cells based on the row and set columns 1 and 2. On the second loop cycle `row is now 209` and the next field is written to merged cells based on that row and set columns 1 and 2.
See the example screenshot.

```
import xlsxwriter

book = xlsxwriter.Workbook('foo.xlsx')
sheet = book.add_worksheet('Sheet1')

my_list = [
            {'field1': [
                {'name': 'value1', 'description': "this is descr1..."},
            ]},
            {'field2': [
                {'name': 'value2', 'description': "this is descr2..."},
            ]}
]

### Use zip to combine range count with the field data 
for (row, field) in zip(range(206, 1000, 3), my_list):
    for fname, values in field.items():
        sheet.merge_range(row, 1, row+2, 1, values[0]['name'])
        sheet.merge_range(row, 2, row+2, 2, values[0]['description'])

book.close()
```

Output for given example
[image]

If you do only have the one field to add then remove the loop and just use the `sheet.merge_range` lines as they are.